# Using Linq to Entities to find the best match in table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table with two columns that will be used as filtering criteria. Using Linq to Entities, I want to pass in two values and always return the closest match. For example, (1,2) should return (1,2) not (null,2) as the closest. If neither value finds a match, then the Null, Null column match is used.

Below is the sample code.

If 3,3 is passed in the first Data (null,null) should be returned since there are no matches.

If 1,3 is passed in , the second Data (1,null) should be returned.

If 3,2 is passed in , the third Data (null,2) should be returned.

If 1,2 is passed in, the fourth Data(1,2) should be returned.

Is this possible to do in one Linq query since it is generating a database hit?

```
public class Data
        {
            public string prop1 { get; set; }
            public  string prop2 { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Data> datas = new List<Data>
                                   {
                                       new Data
                                           {
                                               prop1 = null,
                                               prop2 = null
                                           },
                                       new Data
                                           {
                                               prop1 = "1",
                                               prop2 = null
                                           },
                                       new Data
                                           {
                                               prop1 = null,
                                               prop2 = "2"
                                           },
                                       new Data
                                           {
                                               prop1 = "1",
                                               prop2 = "2"
                                           }
                                   };


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could simply do something like

```
    Data def = new Data { prop1 = null, prop2 = null };
    var result = (from d in datas
                  where d.prop1 == value1 || d.prop2 == value2
                  orderby (d.prop1 == value1 ? 8 : 0) + (d.prop2 == value2 ? 4 : 0) + (d.prop1 == null ? 2: 0) + (d.prop2 == null ? 1 : 0) descending
                  select d).FirstOrDefault() ?? def;
```

where value1 and value2 are the 2 string to search for, should run as 1 query (didn't test)

Comment: This doesn't cover the case where there is no match for prop1 or prop2 and I want to return the null,null entry.

Comment: Hrm, just add it as extra null check? changed the example to show, if you want it to get the first value from the set just remove the complete where line instead.

Comment: This also doesn't work if the order of the datas is changed in the List :/ For instance, switching entry 3 and 4 will result in (3,2) returning (1,2).

Comment: You didn't say you wanted a null value over a filled out value though